# Return non-anonymous list entity framework - c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables in the database :

Table: Order (item_id)
Table: Item ( item_id)

When I'm doing the inner join in entity framework, as you can see below, I need to return in one list the result to manipulate this. Usually when I do the select in one single table , I return a LIST from the entity with the tables name, but I dont know how can I return a LIST when I have 2 or more entity , I mean, using inner join, I would like to return a List that I can manipulate in other class. When I use for only one entity, it is perfect and easy.

```
public List<????????> getTransdataByStatus(string status)
        {
            contenxt = new Finance_ManagementEntity();

           var  _result = (from a in contenxt.Orders
                           join b in contenxt.Items on a.item_id equals b.item_id
                           select new
                           {
                               a.order_numer,
                               a.total,
                               b.item_code,
                               b.item_qty
                           });
            return _result;
        }
```

I don't know how to return it !! I tried to use the .TOLIST(), but still coming "anonymous".

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a compound model that has a property representing each entity.

```
public class CompoundModel
{
    public Entities.Order { get; set; }
    public Entities.Item { get; set; }
} 

public List<CompoundModel> getTransdataByStatus(string status)
{
    contenxt = new Finance_ManagementEntity();

    var  _result = (from a in contenxt.Orders
                    join b in contenxt.Items on a.item_id equals b.item_id
                    select new CompoundModel
                    {
                        Order = a
                        Item = b
                    });
   return _result;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to flatten your structure, you can create a class that only has four properties.

```
public class CompoundModel
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public int ItemQuantity { get; set }
}

public List<CompoundModel> getTransdataByStatus(string status)
{
    contenxt = new Finance_ManagementEntity();

    var  _result = (from a in contenxt.Orders
                    join b in contenxt.Items on a.item_id equals b.item_id
                    select new CompoundModel
                    {
                        OrderNumber = a.order_number,
                        Total = a.total,
                        ItemCode = b.item_code,
                        ItemQuantity = b.item_qty
                    });
   return _result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a custom type like

```
 public class OrderItems
{
    public int Order_numer { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public string Item_code { get; set; }
    public int Item_qty { get; set; }
}
```

After then modify your function like

```
public List<OrderItems> getTransdataByStatus(string status)
    {
        contenxt = new Finance_ManagementEntity();

        var _result = (from a in contenxt.Orders
                       join b in contenxt.Items on a.item_id equals b.item_id                           
                       select new OrderItems()
                       {
                          Order_numer= a.order_numer,
                          Total= a.total,
                          Item_code=b.item_code,
                          Item_qty=b.item_qty
                       }).ToList();
        return _result;
    }
```

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is this part:

```
select new // This will create an anonymous type
{
    a.order_numer,
    a.total,
    b.item_code,
    b.item_qty
}
```

As the select generates an anonymous type you will get a list of theses anonymous types as a result of the query. In order to get a list typed results, you need to specify the type in the select-clause:

```
select new TypeYouWantToReturn() // This will create an real type
{
    PropA = a.order_numer, // You also need to specify the properties
    PropB = a.total,       // of the class that you want to assign
    PropC = b.item_code,   // the resulting values of the query.
    PropD = b.item_qty
}
```

Now the result of the query will return a list of real types. You need to finally call .ToList() so you get a list instead of the IEnumerable that the select statement will return.